# Is there a Combat log?

Tags: civilization-5

I have found the notification log. However, this does not contain a log of attacks and defences. I use quick combat and sometimes I go, whoa, what hit me?

In my current case, it was a stealth bomber.

Is there a combat log I can sometimes have a look at when I'm confused?

As I begin my turn, I see combat text on the screen. It is difficult to read and does not stay long enough.

**edit: notification log does not show my tank was attacked**

Here is my tank that was bombarded by a canon.

[image]

Here is the notification log

[image]

**edit 2: Notification of unit death and cause.** Still missing, is what attacked my unit that did not die.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you should not use Quick Combat?

Comment: I will not disable quick combat.

Comment: I really hope they fix this with Civ 6.

Answer (score 2):

The Notification log (available from the piece of paper under the turn counter) will tell you if your unit died, and what delivered the final blow.  I have been unable to locate any log of the individual damage messages that appear on screen, nor have I found any mod which allows you to see these after they have disappeared.

Comment: Actually, the notification on the right when you hover over it tells you what killed the unit.

Comment: Yes, the notification log is simply a log of all those messages that appear on the right.